# Homogeneous differential equation By order reduction method

Tags: differential

How can I solve \begin{equation} y'''+6y''+y'-34y=0 \end{equation} (I) 
by order reduction method, knowing that \begin{equation}
y_1(x)=e^{-4x} cos(x)
\end{equation} is a solution of (I)?

I did: \begin{equation}
y(x)=v(x)e^{-4x} cos(x)
\end{equation} 
And I arrived on
\begin{equation}
p''-p'(6+3tan(x))+p(12tan(x)-2)=0
\end{equation} where
\begin{equation}
p=v'(x)
\end{equation}
But I couln't move on from there.

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPo14.jpg)

Comment: Isn't a homework, I tried, but I didn't, seriously. 
I couldn't solve it by the proposed method, only by the constant coefficients and I would like to know where I went wrong. Sorry about that.

Comment: Show us what you tried and maybe we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake again. I left as far as I could make it.

Comment: Yes, I've wrote correctly! I'll send a pic.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot the basic stuff when facing this kind of differential equations with constant coefficients.

Given $$\begin{equation} y'''+6y''+y'-34y=0 \end{equation}$$ the characteristic equation is $$r^3+6 r^2+r-34=0\implies (r-2)(r^2+8 r+17)=0$$ So,  the roots are
$$r_1=2\qquad r_2=-4-i\qquad r_3=-4+i$$ making the solution to be
$$y=c_1 e^{2 x}+c_2 e^{-4 x} \sin (x)+c_3 e^{-4 x} \cos (x)$$

End of the story.

Comment: Thank you, but I also resolved that. However the statement called for reduction of order. That's my problem, I'm thinking for two long days: it is possíble to do by it? Or was my counselor wrong?